# Regex to match the dollar in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to match everything behind **value:**, including words, hypen, underscore and dollar sign.

Like:

```
Value:      -A--C_Df-$
```

Or

```
Value:      -A--C_Df
```

Or the easy one:

```
Value:      ACDF
```

How do i cover the dollar sign? 
My Regex works except the dollar sign:

```
m/Value:(\s+|\t+)([a-zA-z_-]*)/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the any character `.`:

```
m/Value:\s*(.*)/
```

If you want to use a character class, you just need to escape the dollar sign and the dash that's a literal:

```
m/Value:\s*([a-zA-Z_\-\$]*)/
```

Comment: I already tried to escape but this returns a error: Invalid [] range "_-\$" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/Value:(\s+|\t+)([a-zA-z_-\$ <-- HERE ]*)/

Comment: Escape the dash that's a literal as well, or put it at the end of the character class.

Comment: YES! that makes it working:                                        m/Value:(\s+|\t+)([a-zA-z_\-\$]*)/

Comment: Thats the final one: m/Value:\s*([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\$]*)/

Comment: You did not include digits in your original regex.  You can then utilize the `\w` character class to make your regex a bit shorter: `m/Value:\s*([\w\-\$]*)/`

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to match *everything*, so why not just `.*`?  Otherwise you can just include the `$` in your character class:

```
m/Value:(\s+)([a-zA-Z_$-]*)/
```

Note that `\t` is covered by `\s`.

Comment: I already tried that but it returns a error using perl, it says invalid [] range "_-5" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/Value:(\s+|\t+)([a-zA-z_-5 <-- HERE .016003*)/

Comment: I saw this too and i don't know, i try to run this:                  if (m/Value:(\s+|\t+)([a-zA-Z_$-]*)/){
 print "$2";
}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the dorrar sign?

```
m/Value:(\s+)([\w$-]*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
m/Value:\s*(\S+)/
```

That will match zero or more white space chars (no need for \t, \s includes tabs), followed by one or more non whitespace chars that you can extract.